# Simple site search with Duckduckgo

Tags: search-engine

I would like to add simple site search, using [Duckduckgo](http://duckduckgo.com/search_box.html), limited to search only "example.com".

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search) has solved this, using some JavaScript to add the `site:example.com` filter to the query.

```
<form onsubmit="var txt=$(this).find('input[name=\'q\']'); txt.val(txt.val() + ' site:stackoverflow.com');" action="http://www.duckduckgo.com/" method="get" id="duck-duck-go-search">
  <input type="text" value="" maxlength="255" size="36" name="q">&nbsp;
  <input type="submit" value="DuckDuckGo">
 </form>
```

I'd prefer a solution that does not depend on JavaScript, though.

The URL should be `http://duckduckgo.com/?q=site:example.com%20might`; the `site:example.com` must be added to the `q=` parameter, it seems.

Has anyone found a simple, non JavaScript solution for this?

Comment: I tried a simple form POST to see if maybe it would work, but no, same with GET with site as a key.  You could always ask for the feature: http://duckduckgo.com/feedback.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I contacted DuckduckGo and got a solution from [Weinberg](http://www.gabrielweinberg.com/blog/) himself.

> There actually is a hidden sites param :). Try it!
> Gabriel, http://ye.gg

It was the plural (not site, but sites) that got me confused, but the solution is very simple:

[http://duckduckgo.com/?q=duckduckgo& **sites=** stackoverflow.com](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=duckduckgo&sites=stackoverflow.com)

Or, in a simple HTML form:

```
<form action="https://duckduckgo.com/" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="sites" value="stackoverflow.com">
  <input type="search" name="q">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Though DuckDuckGo utilises Bing results, it will ignore most of a site's pages, even though Bing as at August 2023 has 100% coverage. For comparison, Google only ever lists 4% of a not-so-popular site.